# Live Streaming from android of ip camera or channels

Tags: android

```
String LINK = "rtsp://121.244.145.226:554/prf0/cid_61.sdp";
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();}}
```

here is my code giving error can't play video anyone help please?

> 10-22 12:49:14.875: W/MediaPlayer(21235): info/warning (701, 0) 10-22
>   12:49:35.875: E/MediaPlayer(21235): error (1, -2147483648) 10-22
>   12:49:35.875: E/MediaPlayer(21235): Error (1,-2147483648)

logcat details

Comment: Post logcat details !

Comment: 10-22 12:34:44.075: E/MediaPlayer(21235): error (1, -2147483648)
10-22 12:34:44.075: E/MediaPlayer(21235): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: there are two errors in log cat